# react-native get address from lon lat not displaying

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get address from longitude and latitude. Here's what I have so far :

```
 getAddress(lat, long){
    let apiKey = 'myKey'
    fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${lat},${long}&key=${apiKey}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        const address = responseJson.results[0].formatted_address;
        return address;
    });   
  }
```

I get the right address but when I want to display it, it is not working :

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => (
     <View>
        <Text style={styles.address}>{this.getAddress(item.user.latitude, item.user.longitude)}</Text>
     </View>
  )
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How many addresses are you looking up to then put into your FlatList?

Answer (score 2):

you can callback your asynchronous response and use it.

```js
getAddress(lat, long, callback){
    let apiKey = 'myKey'
    fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${lat},${long}&key=${apiKey}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        const address = responseJson.results[0].formatted_address;
        callback(address);
    });   
  }
```

```js
renderItem = ({ item }) => (
<View>
 {
  this.getAddress(item.user.latitude, item.user.longitude, (value)=><Text
  style={styles.address}
  >{value}</Text>)
 }
</View>
)
```

Comment: first check your fetch api response `console.log(responseJson)`if it console your response than it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the state change instead,

```
componentWillMount(){
this.getAddress(lat,long);
}

getAddress(lat, long){
    let apiKey = 'myKey'
    fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${lat},${long}&key=${apiKey}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        const address = responseJson.results[0].formatted_address;
        this.setState({address})
    });   
  }


renderItem = ({ item }) => (
     <View>
        {this.state.address ? 
              this.state.address.map(singleAddress => 
                  <Text style={styles.address}>{singleAddress}</Text>) 
                : <Text>Loading Data</Text>
        }
     </View>
  )
```

Initially `this.state.address` will be empty so nothing will be displayed, but as soon as you get a value from fetch, it will update the state and upon a change of state, it will re-render and show the correct data.

YOUR WILL VIEW THE BELOW RESULT ON THE SCREEN

This is the result of "address"

[image]

PLAYGROUND:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    address: 'default address, please add API KEY'
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getAddress(40.341, -109.231); //PUT YOUR LOCATION CO-ORDINATES
  }

  //
  getAddress(lat, long) {
    let apiKey = 'myKey' //Make Sure to add your API KEY
    fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${lat},${long}&key=${apiKey}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson.results[0].formatted_address)
        const address = responseJson.results[0].formatted_address;
        this.setState({
          address
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return <p > {
      this.state.address
    } < /p>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Actually this is a result that I don't get,  I only have 6 addresses to get

Comment: I don't really understand you answer 'cause I'm using the renderitem to fill my parameters getAdress(item.user.latitude, item.user.longitude), how can I call it in componentWillMount ?

Comment: I don't know where are you using the renderItem function, but what my code does is 1. componentWillMounnt() will call the function `getAddress` 2. `getAddress` will change the state to the data which you get from `fetch`  3. renderItem, will display the list. It will be much convenient if you post a working code in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is an asynchronous call, which returns a Promise. This is why to get the value out of the response you use the Promise's `then` clause. However, the function `getAddress` does not return the promise. In fact, it returns `undefined`.

The `return` keyword in the `then` clause only returns a new value to be wrapped by the new Promise.

To get this to work you need to return the promise from the function:

```
return fetch(...)
```

And then to use the value that is returned, you can then, again, only use the `then` clause, since this is asynchronous. So in fact, `renderItem` becomes asynchronous as well:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return this.getAddress(item.user.latitude, item.user.longitude)
      .then(address => (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.address}>{address}</Text>
        </View>
      ));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer ! I did this, but when adding return before fetch I get this error : Object are not valid as a React Child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. I'm not quite sure to understand where it's coming from

Comment: I'm not sure what is coming back in `address`, if it's an object, you'll have to turn it into a string before you can place it into a Text tag. Also, since this is asynchronous, you can't directly place this into a `render` method on the component. You'll have to set that into some state that the render function relies on.

Comment: I'm not getting an objet, I've updated my answer and screen the result I get